# Issue in Data Transfer between IOT Hub and Raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi3, iot, azure-iot-hub, windows-10-iot-core

First of all hi to all as it is my first question on stack overflow.
Pardon me if you find alot of mistakes in my question asking format.
I am trying to make follwoing Project 
https://www.hackster.io/wearemakers/get-me-there-bus-intelligent-transportation-system-bits-9a06c1

for my school project but as mentioned in project after receiving data from sensors  on IOT Hub of Azure tables will be created automatically but there is no table created and even i don't know how to check data is received on IOT Hub or not
Here is pic of step where i have encountered problem.
[image: Problem Image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Azure IoT Toolkit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsciot-vscode.azure-iot-toolkit) for VS Code to check whether data is received in IoT Hub.

1. Right-click your device and select **Start Monitoring D2C Message**.
2. The monitored messages will be shown in **OUTPUT** > **Azure IoT Toolkit** view.
3. To stop monitoring, right-click the **OUTPUT** view and select **Stop Monitoring D2C Message**.

[image: Monitor-IoT-Hub-D2C-Message]

You could also check out the [Wiki Page](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-azure-iot-toolkit/wiki) to see the more detailed usage.

If you could see message arrived in IoT Hub, then there should be the problem between IoT Hub and Azure Storage. Otherwise, it should be the problem of your Raspberry pi not sending message.

Answer (score 0):

> i don't know how to check data is received on IOT Hub

You can use Device Explorer to check if data is received by IoT Hub:

[image]

Ref:

"[How to use Device Explorer for IoT Hub devices](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/tools/DeviceExplorer)"

"[Monitor device-to-cloud events](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/tools/DeviceExplorer#monitor)"